# Why Is This Pointer Being Copied Incorrectly? Why Does The Segmentation Fault Not Occur Earlier?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, gdb, initialization

I am debugging a program that reads data from a binary file and puts it into the fields of a `TaggerDataUnigram` object, `TaggerDataUnigram` being a class derived from `TaggerData`. All the reading operations read a number of data objects specified in the file and put the objects into fields of `TaggerData`. Therefore, I defined a function `ReadForNumberToRead` that takes a file and a `Reader*` as arguments, `Reader` being a base class for functors that define how to read the data from the file. Each `Reader` derivative takes a `TaggerData*` as an argument and stores the value of the pointer as a member. Unfortunately, `TaggerData` uses getters and setters, but the getters return references to the fields. So, for example, `OpenClassReader` accesses `TaggerData::open_class` through `tagger_data_pointer_->getOpenClass()`.

---

**Example: `ForbiddingRuleReader`'s Constructor:**

```
ForbiddingRuleReader::ForbiddingRuleReader(
        FILE*& tagger_data_input_file_reference,
        TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer)
        : Reader(tagger_data_input_file_reference, tagger_data_pointer) {}
```

*`tagger_data_pointer_` is a `protected` member of `Reader`.*

```
Reader::Reader(FILE*& tagger_data_input_file_reference,
               TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer)
        : TaggerDataFileInputOutput(tagger_data_input_file_reference),
          tagger_data_pointer_(tagger_data_pointer) {} // tagger_data_pointer_ is initialized.
```

**. . . and the identical constructor of `ArrayTagReader`:**

```
ArrayTagReader::ArrayTagReader(FILE*& tagger_data_input_file_reference,
                               TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer)
        : Reader(tagger_data_input_file_reference, tagger_data_pointer) {}
```

**Their usages are likewise the same:**

```
void TaggerDataUnigram::ReadTheForbiddingRules(
        FILE*& unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference) {
    ForbiddingRuleReader forbidding_rule_reader(
            unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference,
            this);
    ReadForNumberToRead(unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference,
                        &forbidding_rule_reader);
}
[. . .]
void TaggerDataUnigram::ReadTheArrayTags(
        FILE*& unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference) {
    ArrayTagReader array_tag_reader(unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference,
                                    this);
    ReadForNumberToRead(unigram_tagger_data_input_file_reference,
                        &array_tag_reader);
}
```

Needless to say, **the `TaggerDataUnigram` object is not going out of scope.**

---

`OpenClassReader` and `ForbiddingRuleReader` both work perfectly; they store a copy of the file and `TaggerData*` as fields and successively read data from the file and put it into its respective field in `TaggerData`. The problem arises when the `ArrayTagReader` is constructed. Despite sharing an identical constructor and being used the same way as `ForbiddingRuleReader`, ***something goes terribly wrong--`tagger_data_pointer_` does not point to the same location in memory as the `TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer` the object was constructed with!***

```
Breakpoint 1, ArrayTagReader::ArrayTagReader (this=0x7fffffffd640, tagger_data_input_file_reference=@0x7fffffffd720: 0x62a730, tagger_data_pointer=0x7fffffffd8c0)
at array_tag_reader.cc:10
10      : Reader(tagger_data_input_file_reference, tagger_data_pointer) {}
(gdb) print tagger_data_pointer
$1 = (TaggerData *) 0x7fffffffd8c0 <----------
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, ArrayTagReader::operator() (this=0x7fffffffd640) at array_tag_reader.cc:12
12  void ArrayTagReader::operator()() {
(gdb) print tagger_data_pointer_
$2 = (TaggerData *) 0x7fffffffd720 <----------
```

In both `OpenClassReader` and `ForbiddingRuleReader`, `tagger_data_pointer_` is equal to `tagger_data_pointer`.

Strangely, errors do not result immediately, even though the pointer is **clearly** invalid.

```
Breakpoint 3, ArrayTagReader::operator() (this=0x7fffffffd640) at array_tag_reader.cc:12
12  void ArrayTagReader::operator()() {
(gdb) print *tagger_data_pointer_
$3 = {_vptr.TaggerData = 0x62a730, open_class = std::set with 0 elements, forbid_rules = std::vector of length 275736, capacity -17591907707330 = {{tagi = -1972060027,
  [. . .]
```

However, upon the first call of `TagIndexReader::operator()`, the program encounters a segmentation fault, specifically `SIGSEGV`. It's no surprise; though `TagIndexReader`'s `tagger_data_pointer_` is valid, a great part of the `TaggerDataUnigram` object was compromised.

```
Breakpoint 4, TagIndexReader::operator() (this=0x7fffffffd650) at tag_index_reader.cc:7
7   void TagIndexReader::operator()() {
(gdb) print tagger_data_pointer_
$16 = (TaggerData *) 0x7fffffffd8c0 <---------- This is the correct value.
(gdb) print *tagger_data_pointer_
$17 = {_vptr.TaggerData = 0x41e5b0 <vtable for TaggerDataUnigram+16>, 
  open_class = std::set with 6467592 elements<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x5200000051>,
```

Why is `tagger_data_pointer` being copied incorrectly? Why does the program not encounter a segmentation fault immediately after trying to write to invalid memory? How can I resolve this issue?
Thank you for your time.

---

**Update:**
These might be useful:

```
void ArrayTagReader::operator()() {
    std::wstring array_tag = Compression::wstring_read(
            tagger_data_file_reference_);
    tagger_data_pointer_->getArrayTags().push_back(array_tag);
}

void ReadForNumberToRead(
        FILE* tagger_data_input_file_reference,
        Reader* pointer_to_a_reader) {
    for (int unsigned number_to_read =
         Compression::multibyte_read(tagger_data_input_file_reference);
         number_to_read != 0;
         --number_to_read) {
        pointer_to_a_reader->operator()();
  }
}
```

---

**Update:**
Somehow, I missed the declaration of `tagger_data_poiner_` in `ArrayTagReader`; making the pointers `const` generated the compiler error that brought this to my attention. What I still don't understand is why:

1. The compiler didn't complain about the use of an uninitialized pointer.
2. The program did not encounter a segmentation fault when trying to modify e.g. `tagger_data_poiner_->getArrayTags()`.

Comment: Valgrind................

Comment: @MitchWheat valgrind only tells me `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` a bunch of times, with the backtrace leading to the first use of `ArrayTagReader::operator()`--something that happens after the pointer changes value.

Comment: (Not your main issue) Are these functions opening new files?  Probably you should use `FILE*` and not `FILE*&` as your argument type.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a raw pointer in one of your classes.  Do you have a suitable copy constructor/assignment operator to do a deep copy or have you prohibited copying them?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I do have a copy constructor, but why would I need one? All I do is dereference `tagger_data_pointer_`, which should point to the original class.

Comment: Perhaps you don't, but the fragments of code and wall of text make it hard to understand what's actually going on.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added the code for `ArrayTagReader::operator()` and `ReadForNumberToRead`. My apologies for lack of clarity.

Comment: @downvoter What is wrong with my question? I showed my research, posted what code I thought was necessary, and I'm doing my best to clarify any confusion presently. At least tell me what I did wrong so I can ask a better question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`tagger_data_pointer_` does not point to the same location in memory as the `TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer` the object was constructed with"

That generally means the value has been overwritten. A very common cause is an buffer overflow in the preceding field, or less common an _under_flow in the following field. It also explains why this is a problem that occurs only n one of your two classes; the other class has other neighbors. Still, not all overwrites are buffer over/underflows. Invalid typecasting is another possible problem.

Since you don't mean to change the pointer, do make it `const`. A second debugging technique is to replace the field with an array of 3 identical copies. Create a function that checks if all three are the same, throws if not, and otherwise return the single value. In the places where you dereferenced the pointer, you now call this check function. This gives you a good chance to detect the exact nature of the change. Even more fancy algorithms add extra padding data with known values.

Comment: I seem to have overlooked the declaration of a `tagger_data_pointer_` in `ArrayTagReader`, thus overriding the otherwise correct `tagger_data_pointer_` in `Reader`. Making the pointer `const` generated a compiler error due to the overriding pointer not being initialized. I find it strange that the compiler allowed me to use an uninitialized pointer, though.

Comment: You may want to check the warning level of your compiler. When doing so, be aware that this isn't called _overriding_ but _shadowing_. Member functions (methods) override, member data shadows.

Answer (score 0):

> Despite sharing an identical constructor and being used the same way as ForbiddingRuleReader

I'm not sure why you think these are important, but I can tell you that according to the C++ standard, these have absolutely no relevance concerning whether two types have the same memory layout or whether one can `reinterpret_cast` (or the moral equivalent) between them.

Comment: Perhaps you're simply confused that one appears to work while the other doesn't... if so, chances are they are both causing "undefined behavior", since both appearing to work and crashing horribly are reasonable outcomes of UB.

Comment: I'm not saying the classes are identical--they certainly aren't. However, I would expect them both to copy `tagger_data_pointer` to `tagger_data_pointer_` successfully. (especially since they just pass this argument on to the base constructor!) Why one works and the other ends up with a different memory address, I have no idea.

Comment: @High-rise_9999: I think that pointer is correct, since the vtable pointer has the right value.  It looks more like you have overwritten part of your object... which you already mentioned.  Why do you think the pointer is wrong, then?

Comment: It has a different address. The `TaggerDataUnigram` object is at address `0x7fffffffd8c0`, which `tagger_data_pointer` matches, but somehow `tagger_data_pointer_` ends up with the value of `0x7fffffffd720`. Even though I'm editing the members of the `TaggerDataUnigram` object, the object's address itself shouldn't change.

Comment: @High-rise_9999: What is the declaration of `tagger_data_pointer_`?  Is there any inheritance going on?

Comment: `TaggerData* tagger_data_pointer_;`
Yes, there is inheritance. It's a member of `Reader`. Every `Reader` derivative passes its base constructor a `TaggerData*`. (and a file as well)

Comment: @High-rise_9999: But there's also inheritance in the `TaggerData`, according to your question.  Is it possible you're comparing a `TaggerData` pointer to a `TaggerDataUnigram` pointer?

Comment: `TaggerDataUnigram` is a derived class of `TaggerData`. As I understand it, a `TaggerDataUnigram*` can be used as a `TaggerData*`.

Comment: @High-rise_9999: In your high-level language, yes.  But the compiler is automatically adding the right offset to locate the base class subobject... an upcast can change the numeric value of the pointer.  (And when multiple inheritance is used, it has to)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to read your code properly as everything but the "UPDATE" is extremely messy and very hard to read for anyone but the author. The UPDATE part seems OK. So I'll just drop by a few tips on copying using pointers (as I recently saw that many people make these mistakes) and maybe it helps.

1. Make sure you're not just copying from or to a memory location that is not "marked" as allocated. In other words, if you have a pointer and you're just copying data in array to memory location it points to, nothing stops your program or other programs currently running on the computer to modify that area. You first allocate space (using new, malloc etc.) and then you can copy from/to it.

   `type *p = new type[size];`
2. Even if you've satisfied point 1, make sure copied space doesn't exceed `size`.

Advice on the question, by comments on it (I can't comment ATM)...

You may be a really good programmer. But you'll make mistakes. Meaning you'll have to find them. Meaning you should keep your code tidy. But there's far more **crucial** reason for being tidy. People reading your code don't really know where everything "should" be. For them reading a messy code is **mission impossible**. That's important because someone might have to continue your work for the company on your code. Or if you're looking for help from other programmers, like you're doing right now, you need people to get you.

An indentation should be 1 tab or 4 spaces (you can't use tab on StackOverflow), for every sub-block in your code (covered with { }), unless if the block is empty.

If an instruction is continuing in the next row because of the length, it also deserves an indent. In this case you can also add additional tabs or spaces to make everything look nice. For example, if you have an equation long enough to be separated in 3 rows, you can make every row start from '=' of the first row.

"UPDATE" section looks much better than the rest, but you should still use 4-space indent instead of 2-space indent.